# What is the "three-part commitment form" for Irish visa?

Tags: visas, ireland

After applying for a long-stay visa of Ireland, submitted to their embassy in Canada, I received a phone call from the embassy telling me that I should have also sent them a signed "three-part commitment" form. The person said the form, which is about asserting that I will leave the state at the end of the visa period, may be found in https://www.irishimmigration.ie/ but I cannot find anything there. I tried to call them and send them a webform inquiry, but nobody answers.

Does one know what this form is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the site that you mentioned ([How to apply for long term study visa - Immigration Service Delivery](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-study-in-ireland/what-are-my-study-visa-options/how-to-apply-for-long-term-study-visa/)), it seems that it is not really a form but a letter (I emphasized the relevant part in italic):

> ## Documents Required
>
> [...]
>
> ### Application letter
>
> Your letter must include your full name and postal address, and the:
>
> - Reason you want to come to Ireland
> - Dates you plan to arrive and leave.
>
> *Your letter must also include a commitment from you that you will:*
>
> - *Obey the conditions of your visa in full*
> - *Not rely on public services (for example, public hospitals) or become a burden on the State*
> - *Leave Ireland before your immigration permission expires.*
>
> ### Application Letter
>
> A signed letter of application including your full contact details:
>
> - Outlining your reason for wanting to come to Ireland
> - giving details of any members of your family who are currently in Ireland, or any other EU Member State
> - Undertaking that you will observe the conditions of your visa, >     that you will not become a burden on the State, and that you will > leave the State on the expiry of your permission to remain, and
> - Where the course you now wish to study does not naturally follow on or relate to your educational/employment history, giving valid reasons, supported by documentary evidence (where available), for this change.

Comment: "Not rely on public hospitals" - what happens if the traveller gets sick, or has an accident, during their stay?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: A traveller must provide a travel insurance plan as a required document for visa.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm The clue is in the word _public_. You can spend as much time as you like in a private hospital.

Comment: a strict reading might forbid you from using public transit, visiting a library or free museum, or using a city park. But such are border rules - declare all plant products! No, don't waste my time with your wooden pencil! Declare all medications! No, not the 4 painkillers in your carryon! You can't visit here if you might ever want to live here (the US especially does this one) but you also can't visit if you don't have a good reason for wanting to be here.... sigh.

Comment: @OscarBravo Are you expected to tell your ambulance driver not to take you to the nearest A&E if it's a public hospital?

Comment: @KateGregory to a degree it's all an IQ test designed to weed out people who are too honest and don't know how to play the game.